angular page content doesn't load
I am pretty new to angular and this is my first big project. I have a set of resources(images, js files, css file). I have different components which use them.
However the page is not loading them. I am not able to figure out why.
This is my index.html page:


  <app-root></app-root>
  <app-header></app-header>

  <app-home></app-home>
  <app-footer></app-footer>



this is my app.component.html:


<router-outlet></router-outlet>



This is the content of header.component.html:


<header id="header" class="header d-flex align-items-center fixed-top">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <title>Index - Squadfree Bootstrap Template</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">

  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link href="assets/img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
  <link href="assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">

  <!-- Fonts -->
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" rel="preconnect">
  <link href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" rel="preconnect" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  
     <div class="container-fluid container-xl position-relative d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">

      <a href="index.html" class="logo d-flex align-items-center">
        <!-- Uncomment the line below if you also wish to use an image logo -->
        <!-- <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt=""> -->
        <h1 class="sitename">arandnetworks</h1>
      </a>

      <nav id="navmenu" class="navmenu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#hero" class="active">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"><span>Dropdown</span> <i class="bi bi-chevron-down toggle-dropdown"></i></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown 1</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"><span>Deep Dropdown</span> <i class="bi bi-chevron-down toggle-dropdown"></i></a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Dropdown 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Deep Dropdown 2</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <i class="mobile-nav-toggle d-xl-none bi bi-list"></i>
      </nav>

    </div>
  </header>



This is the content of the home.component.html:


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<body class="index-page">
<main class="main">

    <!-- Hero Section -->
    <section id="hero" class="hero section accent-background">

      <img src="assets/img/hero-bg.jpg" alt="" data-aos="fade-in">

      <div class="container text-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
        <h2>Welcome to Squad</h2>
        <p>We are team of talented designers making websites with Bootstrap</p>
        <a href="#about" class="btn-scroll" title="Scroll Down"><i class="bi bi-chevron-down"></i></a>
      </div>

    </section><!-- /Hero Section -->

    <!-- About Section -->
    <section id="about" class="about section">

      <div class="container">

        <div class="row gy-5">

          <div class="content col-xl-5 d-flex flex-column" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
            <h3>Voluptatem dignissimos provident quasi</h3>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="about-btn align-self-center align-self-xl-start"><span>About us</span> <i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i></a>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xl-7" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">
            <div class="row gy-4">

              <div class="col-md-6 icon-box position-relative">
                <i class="bi bi-briefcase"></i>
                <h4><a href="" class="stretched-link">Corporis voluptates sit</a></h4>
                <p>Consequuntur sunt aut quasi enim aliquam quae harum pariatur laboris nisi ut aliquip</p>
              </div><!-- Icon-Box -->

              <div class="col-md-6 icon-box position-relative">
                <i class="bi bi-gem"></i>
                <h4><a href="" class="stretched-link">Ullamco laboris nisi</a></h4>
                <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt</p>
              </div><!-- Icon-Box -->

              <div class="col-md-6 icon-box position-relative">
                <i class="bi bi-broadcast"></i>
                <h4><a href="" class="stretched-link">Labore consequatur</a></h4>
                <p>Aut suscipit aut cum nemo deleniti aut omnis. Doloribus ut maiores omnis facere</p>
              </div><!-- Icon-Box -->

              <div class="col-md-6 icon-box position-relative">
                <i class="bi bi-easel"></i>
                <h4><a href="" class="stretched-link">Beatae veritatis</a></h4>
                <p>Expedita veritatis consequuntur nihil tempore laudantium vitae denat pacta</p>
              </div><!-- Icon-Box -->

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </section><!-- /About Section -->

    <!-- Services Section -->
    <section id="services" class="services section">

      <!-- Section Title -->
      <div class="container section-title" data-aos="fade-up">
        <h2>Services</h2>
        <p>Necessitatibus eius consequatur ex aliquid fuga eum quidem sint consectetur velit</p>
      </div><!-- End Section Title -->

      <div class="container">

        <div class="row gy-4">

          <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 d-flex" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
            <div class="service-item position-relative">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bi bi-activity icon"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="service-details.html" class="stretched-link">Lorem Ipsum</a></h4>
              <p>Voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi</p>
            </div>
          </div><!-- End Service Item -->

          <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 d-flex" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">
            <div class="service-item position-relative">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bi bi-bounding-box-circles icon"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="service-details.html" class="stretched-link">Sed ut perspici</a></h4>
              <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore</p>
            </div>
          </div><!-- End Service Item -->

          <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 d-flex" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="300">
            <div class="service-item position-relative">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bi bi-calendar4-week icon"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="service-details.html" class="stretched-link">Magni Dolores</a></h4>
              <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia</p>
            </div>
          </div><!-- End Service Item -->

          <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6 d-flex" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="400">
            <div class="service-item position-relative">
              <div class="icon"><i class="bi bi-broadcast icon"></i></div>
              <h4><a href="service-details.html" class="stretched-link">Nemo Enim</a></h4>
              <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis</p>
            </div>
          </div><!-- End Service Item -->

        </div>

      </div>

    </section><!-- /Services Section -->

    <!-- Stats Section -->
    <section id="stats" class="stats section light-background">

      <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">

        <div class="row gy-4">

          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="stats-item">
              <i class="bi bi-emoji-smile"></i>
              <span data-purecounter-start="0" data-purecounter-end="232" data-purecounter-duration="1" class="purecounter"></span>
              <p><strong>Happy Clients</strong> <span>consequuntur quae</span></p>
            </div>
          </div><!-- End Stats Item -->

          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="stats-item">
              <i class="bi bi-journal-richtext"></i>
              <span data-purecounter-start="0" data-purecounter-end="521" data-purecounter-duration="1" class="purecounter"></span>
              <p><strong>Projects</strong> <span>adipisci atque cum quia aut</span></p>
            </div>
          </div><!-- End Stats Item -->

          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="stats-item">
              <i class="bi bi-headset"></i>
              <span data-purecounter-start="0" data-purecounter-end="1453" data-purecounter-duration="1" class="purecounter"></span>
              <p><strong>Hours Of Support</strong> <span>aut commodi quaerat</span></p>
            </div>
          </div><!-- End Stats Item -->

          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="stats-item">
              <i class="bi bi-people"></i>
              <span data-purecounter-start="0" data-purecounter-end="32" data-purecounter-duration="1" class="purecounter"></span>
              <p><strong>Hard Workers</strong> <span>rerum asperiores dolor</span></p>
            </div>
          </div><!-- End Stats Item -->

        </div>

      </div>

    </section><!-- /Stats Section -->

    <!-- Call To Action Section -->
    <section id="call-to-action" class="call-to-action section accent-background">

      <img src="assets/img/cta-bg.jpg" alt="">

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
          <div class="col-xl-10">
            <div class="text-center">
              <h3>Call To Action</h3>
              <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
              <a class="cta-btn" href="#">Call To Action</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </section><!-- /Call To Action Section -->
  

    <!-- Contact Section -->
    <section id="contact" class="contact section">

      <!-- Section Title -->
      <div class="container section-title" data-aos="fade-up">
        <h2>Contact</h2>
        <p>Necessitatibus eius consequatur ex aliquid fuga eum quidem sint consectetur velit</p>
      </div><!-- End Section Title -->

      <div class="container" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">

        <div class="row gy-4">

          <div class="col-lg-5">

            <div class="info-wrap">
              <div class="info-item d-flex" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">
                <i class="bi bi-geo-alt flex-shrink-0"></i>
                <div>
                  <h3>Address</h3>
                  <p>A108 Adam Street, New York, NY 535022</p>
                </div>
              </div><!-- End Info Item -->

              <div class="info-item d-flex" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="300">
                <i class="bi bi-telephone flex-shrink-0"></i>
                <div>
                  <h3>Call Us</h3>
                  <p>+1 5589 55488 55</p>
                </div>
              </div><!-- End Info Item -->

              <div class="info-item d-flex" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="400">
                <i class="bi bi-envelope flex-shrink-0"></i>
                <div>
                  <h3>Email Us</h3>
                  <p>info@example.com</p>
                </div>
              </div><!-- End Info Item -->

              <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d48389.78314118045!2d-74.006138!3d40.710059!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c25a22a3bda30d%3A0xb89d1fe6bc499443!2sDowntown%20Conference%20Center!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1676961268712!5m2!1sen!2sus" frameborder="0" style="border:0; width: 100%; height: 270px;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-7">
            <form action="../forms/contact.php" method="post" class="php-email-form" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">
              <div class="row gy-4">

                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <label for="name-field" class="pb-2">Your Name</label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" id="name-field" class="form-control" required="">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <label for="email-field" class="pb-2">Your Email</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email-field" required="">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <label for="subject-field" class="pb-2">Subject</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject-field" required="">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <label for="message-field" class="pb-2">Message</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="10" id="message-field" required=""></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                  <div class="loading">Loading</div>
                  <div class="error-message"></div>
                  <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>

                  <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
                </div>

              </div>
            </form>
          </div><!-- End Contact Form -->

        </div>

      </div>

    </section><!-- /Contact Section -->

  </main>
  <a href="#" id="scroll-top" class="scroll-top d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><i class="bi bi-arrow-up-short"></i></a>

  <!-- Preloader -->
  <div id="preloader"></div>
 
    <!-- Vendor JS Files -->
    <script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/aos/aos.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/purecounter/purecounter_vanilla.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/glightbox/js/glightbox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
  
    <!-- Main JS File -->
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

  </body>
  </html>



This is the content of the footer.component.html:


<footer id="footer" class="footer dark-background">

  <div class="container footer-top">
    <div class="row gy-4">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 footer-about">
        <a href="index.html" class="logo d-flex align-items-center">
          <span class="sitename">test</span>
        </a>
        <div class="footer-contact pt-3">
          <p>New York, NY 535022</p>
          <p class="mt-3"><strong>Phone:</strong> <span>+1 5589 55488 55</span></p>
          <p><strong>Email:</strong> <span>info@example.com</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="social-links d-flex mt-4">
          <a href=""><i class="bi bi-twitter-x"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 footer-links">
        <h4>Useful Links</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Terms of service</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Privacy policy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 footer-links">
        <h4>Our Services</h4>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Product Management</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Marketing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 footer-newsletter">
        <h4>Our Newsletter</h4>
        <p>Subscribe to our newsletter and receive the latest news about our products and services!</p>
        <form action="forms/newsletter.php" method="post" class="php-email-form">
          <div class="newsletter-form"><input type="email" name="email"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe"></div>
          <div class="loading">Loading</div>
          <div class="error-message"></div>
          <div class="sent-message">Your subscription request has been sent. Thank you!</div>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container copyright text-center mt-4">
    <p>© <span>Copyright</span> <strong class="px-1 sitename">Squadfree</strong> <span>All Rights Reserved</span></p>
    <div class="credits">
      <!-- All the links in the footer should remain intact. -->
      <!-- You can delete the links only if you've purchased the pro version. -->
      <!-- Licensing information: https://bootstrapmade.com/license/ -->
      <!-- Purchase the pro version with working PHP/AJAX contact form: [buy-url] -->
      Designed by <a href="https://bootstrapmade.com/">BootstrapMade</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</footer>



this is the content of angular.json:


{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "myfirstproject": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/myfirstproject",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",myfirstproject
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "myfirstproject:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "myfirstproject:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "myfirstproject:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets/img/portfolio",
              "src/assets/img/team",
              "src/assets/img/testimonials"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.mini.css",
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/assets/css/main.css",
              "src/assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/assets/vendor/glightbox/css/glightbox.min.css",
              "src/assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css",
              "src/assets/vendor/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css",
              "src/assets/vendor/aos/aos.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/main.js",
              "src/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
              "src/assets/vendor/php-email-form/validate.js",
              "src/assets/vendor/aos/aos.js",
              "src/assets/vendor/purecounter/purecounter_vanilla.js",
              "src/assets/vendor/glightbox/js/glightbox.min.js",
              "src/assets/vendor/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js",
              "src/assets/vendor/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.min.js",
              "src/assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}




I want to add that inside the folder of each component I have an asset
folder contenting the css files. I also have an asset folder just under src folder,  > at the same level as app folder. I am not sure that this is the best structure but  > I have been trying to have the asset at src/assets level but it did not work.

These are my ts file for the components above


// header.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css',
     './assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
     './assets/vendor/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css',
    './assets/vendor/aos/aos.css',
    './assets/vendor/glightbox/css/glightbox.min.css',
    './assets/css/main.css'
  ]
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  headerLabels = ["Home","Contact"];
}


// footer.component.ts


import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css',
     './assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
     './assets/vendor/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css',
    './assets/vendor/aos/aos.css',
    './assets/vendor/glightbox/css/glightbox.min.css',
    './assets/css/main.css'
  ]
})
export class FooterComponent {

}

// home.component.ts


import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output,  ViewEncapsulation,ViewChild, ContentChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { UnlessDirective } from '../unless.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css',
     './assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
     './assets/vendor/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css',
    './assets/vendor/aos/aos.css',
    './assets/vendor/glightbox/css/glightbox.min.css',
    './assets/css/main.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class HomeComponent  {

@Input() lblHome: string = 'Home';
@Input() lblOurServices: string = 'Our Services';
@Input() lblContactUs: string = 'Contact us';
@Output() mouseOveronList = new EventEmitter<{}>();
testcustomdirective:boolean=false;
lblPage: string='hi';
displayPage= false;
lblCenterContent='r';
@ViewChild('userWish') userWishInput:any; 
  @ContentChild('contentParagraph')
  paragraph!: ElementRef;

getHomeLabel(){
 return this.lblHome;
}
getOurServicesLabel(){
  return this.lblOurServices;
}

getContactUsLabel() {
  return this.lblContactUs;
}

setHomeLabel(homeLabel:string){
  this.lblHome = homeLabel;
}

setOurServicesLabel(ourServicesLabel:string){
  this.lblOurServices = ourServicesLabel;
}

setContactUsLabel(contactUsLabel:string){
  this.lblContactUs = contactUsLabel;
}
isFinalDesign(){
  return false;
}
goToHome(page:string){
  return this.lblPage=page;
}

onTextInput(event:Event){
  this.lblPage= (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value;
}

isToDisplay(){
  this.displayPage= true;
}


}

// app.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
}





app-root is the root of the Angular application, so anything outside this (like siblings) wont render since it's not inside the angular application, so move the Angular components inside AppComponent.
index.html
<app-root></app-root>

app.component.html
  <app-header></app-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <app-footer></app-footer>

Then you need to render the components like Home inside Angular routing:
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  ...
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}


One more thing is you do not need to add the imports multiple times when the CSS is shared by all components. Go to angular.json and add these styles to styles array.
      "options": {
        ...
        "scripts": [],
        "styles": [
          './node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css',
          './node_modules/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
          './node_modules/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css',
          './assets/vendor/aos/aos.css',
          './assets/vendor/glightbox/css/glightbox.min.css',
          './assets/css/main.css'
        ],
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json"
      }

Standalone (new method) Routing Demo
Modular (old method) Routing Demo

After adding this, you can empty the styles array of your components, since it's already imported globally.
To save you time, directly install bootstrap using npm and reference them like shown above.
npm i bootstrap

